# DocPolynom.m and the 'length' function in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've written a function which contains as a variable an array A whose entries are polynomials (e.g. A{1} = DocPolynom([1 2 3])).

I want to be able to find the length of the vector double(A{i}) for each entry of A. I wrote

> length(double(A{i}));

But here Matlab thinks 'length' is a variable, for some reason. Why is this? How can I get round it?

Thanks

Comment: What error message do you get?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth  My function is quite complicated. When I run it, I get the error:
"length" previously appeared to be used as a function or command, conflicting with its use here as the name of a variable.
 A possible cause of this error is that you forgot to initialize the
 variable, or you have initialized it implicitly using load or eval.

Comment: Can you post a **minimal** test-case?  (Like a 10-15 line function that demonstrates the issue)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yeah, sure. I'll add it to the original question. Though it may take a while - my function relies heavily on other custom functions.

Comment: Great (and you'll probably find the issue while doing this!).  But in the meantime, the most likely cause is that somehow, somewhere, you've ended up creating a variable called `length`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I don't think that's the issue - if I insert "clear length" at the beginning of my function, I still get the same error message (and "length" is still underlined)

Comment: Interesting.  In that case, I'm out of ideas...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I've fixed it! Later in the same function I had typed "length{list}" as opposed to "length(list)". I didn't know Matlab could "see into the future", if you know what I mean. Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems quite likely that you somehow are using length as a variable. Matlab doesn't prevent many value names from being used.

An alternative would be to use the size() function. The size will actually return the size of each dimension. Depending on how the array is used, you could probably use this:

```
size(A{i},1);
```